My Windows application runs very slowly due to PeekMessage()
This application opens a window (no title bar or border) and types 012 based on keyboard input.
For some reason, after compiling using g++, it takes 6-7 seconds to run (in fact, the icon of the executable takes 3-4 seconds to load after compiling, I have never seen that happen). The entire PC lags, and the Task Manager also doesn't show anything like memory leak or high CPU usage or anything.
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define glyph_width 5
#define glyph_height 5

int glyph[3][glyph_width * glyph_height] = {{0,1,1,0,0,
                                  1,0,1,1,0,
                              1,0,0,1,0,
                          1,1,0,1,0,
                          0,1,1,0,0},

                         {0,0,1,0,0,
                                  0,1,1,0,0,
                              0,0,1,0,0,
                          0,0,1,0,0,
                          0,1,1,1,0},

                         {0,1,1,0,0,
                                  1,0,0,1,0,
                              0,0,1,0,0,
                          0,1,0,0,0,
                          1,1,1,1,0}};

bool Running;
uint32_t* BitmapBuffer;
int BitmapWidth;
int BitmapHeight;

BITMAPINFO BitmapInfo;

uint32_t color = 0x00ffffff;
int box_x = 0;
int box_y = 0;

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND WindowHandle, uint32_t Message, WPARAM WParam, LPARAM LParam){
    LRESULT Result = 0;

    switch(Message){
        case WM_CREATE:{
            BitmapWidth = ((CREATESTRUCT*) LParam)->cx;
            BitmapHeight = ((CREATESTRUCT*) LParam)->cy;
            VirtualFree(BitmapBuffer, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
            BitmapBuffer = (uint32_t*) VirtualAlloc(0, BitmapWidth * BitmapHeight * 4, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
            
            BitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFO);
            BitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biWidth = BitmapWidth;
            BitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight = -BitmapHeight;
            BitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
            BitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
            BitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
        } break;
        
        case WM_KEYDOWN:
        case WM_KEYUP:
        case WM_SYSKEYDOWN:
        case WM_SYSKEYUP:{
            uint16_t VKCode = (uint16_t) WParam;
            bool WasKeyDown = (LParam & (1 << 30));
            bool IsKeyDown = !(LParam & (1 << 31)); 
        
            if(IsKeyDown){
                for(int y = 0; y < glyph_height; y++){
                    for(int x = 0; x < glyph_width; x++){
                        if(glyph[VKCode - 48][y * glyph_width + x] == 1)
                        BitmapBuffer[(y + box_y * glyph_height) * BitmapWidth + (x + box_x * glyph_width)] = color;
                    }
                }
                box_x += 1;
            }
        } break;

        case WM_PAINT:{
            SetDIBitsToDevice(GetDC(WindowHandle), 0, 0, BitmapWidth, BitmapHeight, 0, 0, 0, BitmapHeight, BitmapBuffer, &BitmapInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
        } break;
        
        default:{
            Result = DefWindowProc(WindowHandle, Message, WParam, LParam);
        }
    }

    return Result;
}

int main(){

    WNDCLASS WindowClass = {};
    WindowClass.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure;
    WindowClass.lpszClassName = "WindowClassName";
    WindowClass.hInstance = (HINSTANCE) GetModuleHandle(0);
    RegisterClass(&WindowClass);

    AllocConsole();
    freopen("conin$", "r", stdin);
    freopen("conout$", "w", stdout);
    freopen("conout$", "w", stderr);

    HWND Window = CreateWindow(WindowClass.lpszClassName, "Editor", WS_POPUP, 0, 0, 800, 800, 0, 0, WindowClass.hInstance, 0);
    
    ShowWindow(Window, 1);

    Running = true;
    while(Running){
        MSG Message = {};
        while(PeekMessage(&Message, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)){
            TranslateMessage(&Message);
            DispatchMessage(&Message);
        }
        
    }
}

I tried commenting pieces of code and it turns out the inner while(PeekMessage()) loop is the culprit. But without it, the app does nothing except for appearing. I am using PeekMessage() so I can draw onscreen even without any messages.
Why does this happen, and what can I do to fix it?

"... takes 3-4 seconds to load after compiling,..." can be caused by a virus scanner.  Create an exclusion in the virus scanner for your development tree.

Do you really care why PeekMessage is slow or would you rather answers focus on a better alternative to looping on PeekMessage?

@RichardCritten It doesn't happen when I comment out the outer while loop

@user4581301 Both infact

Err..., your program starts like a normal console program and immediately starts a Windows message loop. This is quite unusual and should raise red flags on most antivirus heuristics. As some decide to submit the suspect code to their server, that could explain the 3-4 seconds delay. Did you try to create an exclusion as suggested by @RichardCritten?

@SergeBallesta I don't what that is and I don't have any anitvirus installed.

Furthermore, you are using an active loop (while(Running)) when GetMessage could gently suspend your application as soon as no message remains in the queue. Using PeekMessage for idle time processing was the standard way to execute background tasks without freezing the application window in Windows 3.x, but when no background tasks are to be executed you should always use GetMessage to avoid an active loop.

Just use the "official" "correct" GetMessage loop https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/window-messages and make sure you call BeginPaint and EndPaint in WM_PAINT handling (before and after your SetDIBitsToDevice call) as instructed in official doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/painting-the-window otherwise you're continuously calling SetDIBitsToDevice and eating CPU cycles

@SimonMourier: I'm pretty sure the reason he's calling PeekMessage is there's excised code doing processing in main(). This way of writing is very old and actually correct.

GetDC(WindowHandle) is leaking an HDC on every WM_PAINT message. You need to call ReleaseDC() to free it. Or, just use BeginPaint()/EndPaint() instead, using the HDC that BeginPaint() gives you. Also, there is no reason to call AllocConsole() and freopen() in a console (main()) app. Also, you don't need to call VirtualFree() in WM_CREATE when the buffer hasn't been allocated yet.

@SergeBallesta "your program starts like a normal console program and immediately starts a Windows message loop. This is quite unusual and should raise red flags on most antivirus heuristics." - Based on what threat? Literally, the only difference between the CONSOLE and WINDOWS subsystems is that the system allocates a console for the former but not for the latter. It's entirely normal for a thread in a console application to dispatch messages.

"...and I don't have any anitvirus_"_ if you are on MS-Windows 10+ then you have Microsoft Defender the built-in AV software.

As a side-note, would WM_PAINT actually be dispatched more than once here? Unless you move the window around and/or obstruct it, or something - it doesn't look like anything would invalidate the window to provoke another WM_PAINT from the keyboard input alone.

@500-InternalServerError Following the initial call to ShowWindow() the entire window area is invalidated.

@IInspectable: Sure, but that only happens once, right?

@500-InternalServerError It happens until the invalid region gets validated. That never happens, so WM_PAINT messages are generated indefinitely.

        case WM_PAINT:{
            SetDIBitsToDevice(GetDC(WindowHandle), 0, 0, BitmapWidth, BitmapHeight, 0, 0, 0, BitmapHeight, BitmapBuffer, &BitmapInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
        } break;

Where's BeginPaint and EndPaint? You either need to call them or call ValidateRect otherwise the rectangle remains dirty and will be painted way too often.

This does not sufficiently explain the observed behavior. The code will indeed generate an infinite stream of WM_PAINT messages, but those are low-priority and will not prevent the message loop from dispatching virtually every other message. The GDI object leak is far more impactful.

@IInspectable what is gdi leak? side tangent here but, everytime I program with win32 and want to find why my code doesn't work, I always get to some esoteric thing in answer on some tiny comment in on SO or reddit. Windows API doesn't teach me this shit at all. Or am I the stupid one?

I added ValidateRect(WindowHandle, 0); But now it doesn;t print the characters on screen

@PrateekBana: GDI Leak: the default setting of a window class is pooled Device Context.

The reason it prints nothing is you need to call InvalidateRect() after updating your bitmap.

I don't think telling the OP to call ValidateRect in his WM_PAINT handler is good advice.  MS document what to do, so do it.
